# Twilio Voice volume control

Tags: twilio

I'm running the *Browser Calls for Python - Flask* example, and was wondering if there is a way to control the speaker volume on the Twilio Client side?

On other voice solutions, I used to manipulate the volume via the HTML5  element, but it seems that Twilio doesn't use one.

Comment: I had a dig around in the source code and it looks like Twilio Client uses the Web Audio API to deliver the audio. I'm asking to see if there is a specific way to control the volume and I will get back to you.

Comment: Thanks, let me know if you learn more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I checked with the Twilio Client JS team and the audio is played using the Web Audio API. As such, there is no way, built in or otherwise, to control the volume.

You can get information about the volume from the library though, check the [`Device.audio`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/device#audio) methods and events.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate the feedback.